# How to configure Gradle to use Java classes defined in the default unnamed package?

Tags: java, configuration, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

There are some externally sourced Java classes that happen to be defined all in the default unnamed package, i.e. there are no `package ...` statement at the top of the `.java` source files where these Java classes are defined.  I use these as dependencies in my Java project. The few Java classes I write for my project are also placed in the default unnamed package.  I use IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 to work on this project and set the `.jar` file containing the external Java classes as a library and project dependency.  However, I don't know how to configure Gradle so it properly handles the dependency. Currently, I just "manually" added a configuration for the project as a regular Java Application.  Clicking on 'Run' using the configuration compiles and runs the project OK.

Comment: No special configuration is necessary for this.

Comment: After clicking the default tasks -- is it the right term? -- such as 'buildJava' or 'build' in the Gradle window in IntelliJ IDEA, many errors prints out in the console. The first one is complaining `cannot find symbol \\ symbol  : class SomeExternalClass  \\location: class MyClass`

Comment: Really, do the right thing, and put all your classes in a package. Using the default package is a bad, bad, bad practice that will only cause you trouble.

Comment: Have you verified that simply adding packages makes the Gradle build succeed? I'd think it's a different, unrelated problem.

Comment: No, I don't have the option of adding `package *` statements at the top of the external classes.  It's required to stay in the unnamed default package by my superior. Also this fact is unrelated to this technical question.

Comment: Also, the external classes come in as one JAR file.  I don't know how to put all the contained classes into a package.

Comment: I was stuck trying to figure out a related compilation issue until I found that [you can’t import classes from the unnamed package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package)