# failing to import external library in java project?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, import

Here is a screenshot of netbeans 
[image]

Here, I have imported three jar libraries algs4.jar, stdlib.jar and acm.jar. Netbeans is importing acm finely but not importing algs4.jar and stdlib.jar. As you can see in line 3 there is no error but in line 4 it is showing error in importing, even in line 5 it is not showing algs4 and stdlib? What is going wrong here?

update:
here are some more screenshots.
[image]
Here i have expanded the stdlib.jar. As you can see there is a .java file name AcyclicLP.java(first one) in that .jar.

Comment: Does the _stdlib.jar_ actually contain a _stdlib_ package?

Comment: I opened in archive manager. There are just a lot of .class and corresponding .java files in it. I guess no it's not a package. I want to import those classes in my program. How to do that...

Comment: You don't have to import anything in advance. Just go ahead with your code and when you use a class from one of those jar files, import it in the same way you did the `ConsoleProgram`, with the class' full qualified name. More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Comment: I tried to import that file by 'fully qualified name' method but it is still showing errors. On hovering mouse over those errors they are saying cannot find Symbol AcyclicLP... am i doing something wrong in importing or there is something else going wrong?(i have updated question, have a look at new screenshot)

Comment: [classes from default package can't be imported](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193298/2587435). One of the reasons using default package for classes is advised/warned against by the IDE

Comment: so if i extract all those classes in one folder and work in that folder then it should work. right?