# One source folder doesn't see the other - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I've been trying to create a `.jar` file using some `.png` images as custom icons for my buttons. In order to do this I want to use simple `ResourceLoader` class:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class ResourceLoader {
    static ResourceLoader rl = new ResourceLoader();

    public Image loadImage(String fileName) {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getImage(rl.getClass().getResource("images/"+fileName));
    }
}
```

My problem, however, is that I can't access this class from my `src` package even though I added my `res` folder to the build path.[image]
This picutre shows my current way of adding images - with a path in a constructor of an `ImageIcon` object. This, sadly, doesn't exports pictures permanently to `.jar`. 
What wrong am I doing? I'll be very grateful for any help from You!

Comment: Method loadImage is not static, so content assistant doesn't propose it.

Comment: My mistake, I've changed it. But the problem hasn't gone. The `ResourceLoader` cannot be resolved as a variable...

Comment: Your problem can be also the default package. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package