# Use Another Project Class' Object in a custom package - Java

Tags: java, import, package

I am trying to use Project-1 's class in Project-2's custom package. I did this action you can see below.

> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Projects tab -> Add ->Project1
>   -> OK -> exit the project properties window.

when i use project1's class in default package of project2 there is no problem, but if i use project1's class in a custom package of project2 it doesn't recognise project1's class object.

What should i do for fixing this recognition problem?

Comment: I tested. I got . no error. what is your error ?

Comment: check these two screenshoots http://puu.sh/goEu2/194fe2657f.png , http://puu.sh/goEuq/7344505ea1.png

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i put my first project's class(FooClass in your project) to a custom package,it worked too; thus my problem is solved but i can not understand why it doesnt work if Foo Class is in default package.

Comment: There has many answers for your problem. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)