# Importing Jar Statement

Tags: java, android, jar

Does anyone know how the import statement for the Smokation class under the Smokation.jar file look like? Since its not under a "com.example.so on" I'm quite confused on how to import it. Did I just make my jar file wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try searching in Google its very simple 
"how to add jar file in android studio" , 

Answer:
To see libs folder in the project, choose the project from combobox above the folders. then right click on the .jar file and click add as a library then choose a module then ok. You can see the .jar file in build.gradle file within dependencies block.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question in here.

[How to import a class from default package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package)

Basically you can't import them but use classes with reflection etc.