# Import Java Class that is further up in folder

Tags: java, import

I have the following structure for my java project:

```
-src
    -(default package)
       -Calculator.java
       -AnotherClass.java
       -EvenOneMoreClass.java
       -ui
         -MainWindow.java
```

I know I can include main window in Calculator with `import ui.MainWindow`.  How do I import `AnotherClass.java` into `MainWindow.java`?

**Or, is my structure just wrong for how I want this to work?**

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Mars is what I'm using

Comment: Once you hover over the class reference in MainWindow, does it not give the option to import the class?

Comment: You really shouldn't use the default package and should put those classes inside a package, even if it's "main" or "misc" or "utils" or something. Then your import would be like: import main.AnotherClass;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. See [this existing SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package).

Instead, put your classes into appropriate packages and you will have no problem.