# Netbeans is not recognizing a JAR library

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a weird problem: Netbeans is not recognizing a JAR file added as a library.

I used to have classes in the default package and I was able to access Thing.jar by calling `new Thing();` in the Main class. After I created some packages and reorganized my classes, Netbeans started complaining over that line of code: "cannot find symbol: Class Thing". I tried removing/adding the jar library. It doesn't complain anything and I can see the jar file under projects/libraries. Google also didn't turn up any magic tricks regarding how to add JAR files. I don't understand why this worked inside the default package, but doesn't work in another package.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the classes at the beginning of your file.
If a class is not in the same package java requires an import, even when the jar file is placed in the Libraries.

Comment: It appears it's not possible to import a class which is inside <default package> of a JAR

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the default package if you want the class to be available outside the current jar. It is not possible to import from the default package.

See [How to import a class from default package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package)

Comment: I didn't create the JAR file, I just have to use it.

Comment: I understand the situation as this: (1) You need to import a class from the default package. (2) It is a compile time error to import from the default package. I don't think there is much we can do t help you.

Comment: I chose to decompile the JAR. It appears to be working. Thanks for the link.