# Accessing additional source-folders in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded-resource

[image: ...]

I'm just starting to learn how to work with a res folder in Java... res and src are both in the buildpath however when I try to use ResourceLoader from my programDriver in src, it isn't able to resolve into a type. How do you ''import'' from additional source folders?

This is the resource loader class, if at all relevant:

```
public class ResourceLoader {
private static ResourceLoader rl = new ResourceLoader();
public static Image getImage(String fileName)
{
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(rl.getClass().getResource("images/"+fileName));
}
```

}

Comment: Post code, not images of code.

Comment: I'll add it but I don't see how it will help, the code itself isn't the source of my problem as much as ignorance on how to import a Class from an additional src folder named "res"

Comment: More relevant might be the `ProgramDriver` code, since it is what is not able to find the `ResourceLoader` class.  Anyone who is inclined to help you can't copy/paste the (ideally [mcve]) into their own IDE to attempt to debug the issue.

Comment: agreed, said code has been added, but the image is mostly for the file-structure of the project. I know *why* ResourceLoader can't be resolved into a type... it hasn't been imported. If it were in another package, ez, no problem, regular import statement... My problem is it's in another *source* folder (called "res") and I have no idea how to import it within this context.

Comment: The image of the file structure is useful, yes.  But with a short snippets of both a main program (`ProgramDriver`) attempting to access `ResourceLoader` and a short `ResourceLoader` class, someone attempting to help could copy-paste into their IDE, setup similarly thanks to the project image, could immediately start to diagnose the issue, which is there is no way to ask Eclipse to import a `class` from a `package` with no name.  Without it, the helper has to spend a minute or three creating both classes.  You got an answer an hour after asking the question; it might have been a few minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a class from default package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package)

Comment: Batman? really?? :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import classes from the "default" package.  There is no `import default.ResourceLoader` statement.  The use of the "default package" is discouraged for a reason; this is it (or one of them, anyway).

Move your ResourceLoader into it's own package, and then you can use an import statement in your `ProgramDriver` java file.

```
package resPkg;

public class ResourceLoader {
    // ...
}
```

---

```
package program;

import resPkg.ResourceLoader;

class ProgramDriver {
    // ...
}
```