# How can I import Application class in common directory

Tags: java, import, package

This is my directory structure:

```
src
|-common
| |-AppManager.java
| |-DesignConstants.java
|-controller
|-view
|-Application.java
```

I have tried to import "src.Application" class in "src.common.AppManager".
But, It's not working. How can I do that?

```
package common;

import view.MainPanelView;
import Application; // Error :: Class 'Application' is in the default package

public class AppManager {
    private static class Holder {
        public static final AppManager INSTANCE = new AppManager();
        public static final MainPanelView MAIN_PANEL_VIEW = new MainPanelView();
    } // Holder Inner Class

    public static AppManager getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    } // getInstance()

    public MainPanelView getMainPanelView() {
        return Holder.MAIN_PANEL_VIEW;
    } // getMainPanelView()
} // AppManager Class
```

Comment: What is the error that you see? Can you share some code?

Comment: package common;

import view.MainPanelView;
import Application; // Error :: Class 'Application' is in the default package

Comment: Please edit the original question and add the code.

Comment: Hey Welcome to Stack Overflow! To write good quality questions make sure to include all relevant information in your question, and try not to depend on third party links or images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a class from default package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package)

Answer (score 0):

`src` is not a package but a source folder.`

This means, that `AppManager` is in the package `common` and not `src.common`(see the package declaration: `package common` on the top of the class).

The `Application` class however, is in the default package (not a specific package).

Therefore, it has no `package` declaration at it's top and it can be only used by other classes within the default package.

It is recommended to create a package containing all classes of your project.

For example, you can use this directory structure

```
src
|-yourrootpackagename
| |-common
| | |-AppManager.java
| | |-DesignConstants.java
| |-controller
| |-view
| |-Application.java
```

With this structure, you can import `yourrootpackagename.Application` from `yourrootpackagename.common.AppManager`.

Don't forget to change the package declarations of your existing classes. For example, the `AppManager` class should start with:

```
package yourrootpackagename.common;
```

By the way, it is a good practice to create a root package containing to reverse-domain-name of your organisation and your project name.

For example, for stack overflow, the package would be something like `com.stackoverflow.yourproject`. You may want to do that with your reverse domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't import classes that aren't in a package. 
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2193298/4425643

You'll have to move Application.java into its own package (folder).

For example, create a folder called main inside the src folder and refactor Application.java by moving it into the package main.