# Global variables in java

Tags: java, global-variables

I want to make a class in java that is accessible to all other classes in my project.

I created this in the default package and now it cannot be seen.  What is the best way to do this in java?

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java

Comment: good reference. worth noting that you can't import from the default package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically the default package is not used, your package would be something like `com.yourdomain.mypackage`. As long as you declare the class as `public`, it can be seen by all classes as long as they import it.

The class would look like

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage;

public class MyClass {...}
```

Then the user of the class would be

```
package com.mycompany.anotherpackage;
import com.mycompany.myPackage.MyClass;

private final MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```