# Eclipse + Java: How do I import classes from the default package?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have classes in an Entities package, but I still want to run import stuff that is in the default package... how do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the syntax to import a class in a default package in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

Sorry.

Though I'm quoting the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package), you can check out the [ORACLE reference](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4989710) that says that that is intended behaviour.

I recommend moving your stuff to a named package.

If you absolutely cannot re-factor, you can try using reflection to access it. Again, check the answer linked above.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science) - Basically, it is Java's way of creating instances of classes and calling methods without importing the class. It is a huge pain, and I don't recommend it.