# How do I avoid unnecessary class references in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, lwjgl

I have two java classes (.java files). I want to be able to create new instances of an object in one class that were defined in the other class, without referencing the class name each time. In C# there are `#using` and includes, but I am only able to use `import <pre-compiled code>` in java.  Is there a way to do this:

```
import TestClass;
```

and then simply call a function inside it **without** using

```
TestClass.TestFunction()
```

every time?  I simply need to have all of my functions and objects to be separate from my `Main` class.

Comment: we have to know whether two classes are in the same package or not

Comment: Look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Comment: @RajuGujarati no, not really.

Comment: 1. Yes, same package
2. Will check that out
3. xD I think them being in the same package it what is screwing things up.  Possibly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `TestFunction` is a static method in `TestClass`, you can use a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html):

```
import static TestClass.TestFunction;
// or
import static TestClass.*;
```

and then call it without using the class qualifier:

```
TestFunction(...);
```

Note this can lead to confusing/hard-to-read code – **use static imports sparingly.**

Comment: I get a "Cannot find symbol" error on the class name, but it certainly does exist.  This is why I am confused.
I have tried so many different things and still get errors.

Comment: You need to import the fully-qualified class name. You didn't give one in your question so I didn't put it into my answer. As an example, however, you could statically import all of the functions and constants from [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) like so: `import static java.lang.Math.*;`

Comment: I understand, but this is a class I have created.  It is a .java file, and it is in the same directory as my Main.java project file.  No prefixes I add seem to fix it.

Comment: What package are these two classes in? I repeat: you need to import the **fully-qualified** class name.

Comment: I can't figure out the fully qualified class name, I literally switched from C# to java about 6 hours ago.  
These are both in `MYPROJECT -> Source Packages -> <default package>`  according to net beans.

Comment: Ah - there's your problem. **Don't use the default package.** [Classes in the default package cannot be imported.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3835279/139010)

Comment: Got ya!  I moved it to its own package in the project called TESTPACKAGE.  Now how would I reference it?
Doesn't seem to find the class, but it sees the package.

Comment: `import static TESTPACKAGE.TestClass.TestFunction;`

Comment: There is my problem.  I am not going to import 30 functions for use.  That is crazy.  I need to import a class, so I can call all of the functions without references.

Comment: Thus the wildcard: `import static TESTPACKAGE.TestClass.*;` ...it's right there in my answer.

Comment: I know you guys probably think I am stupid, but I am still getting errors.  
Cannot find symbol:
Class: TestClass.  Your code didn't work. And I know, it just should work.

Comment: Solved.  Using the **refracting** option, suddenly everything started working.  Also changing a few things to public after that removed all remaining errors.  Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using netbeans then you won't be finding any issue during the import of any java classes. And yeah that's true you can have only "pre-compiled classes" as import statement. If you are running on notepad then you need to compile your independent classes first and then your dependent classes. And if you use Netbeans or Eclipse or any other IDE then you do not have to worry they will manage by themselves, you just have to use proper package and class names
You can have two types of imports

```
import package1.Class1;
import static package1.Class2;
```

With the first one you can create object of Class1 (or any other class if present in Class1) and invoke the methods
With the second one you can directly call the static methods of Class2 without referencing it with classname

**Updated**
See [tutorials on packages in JAVA](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=291)

Comment: How do I get the package name that my project is in?  Because the package is the same for both the class I am importing and the class being imported to.

Comment: when you write your java code package name is written as the first statement.. See your java code where they reside `package p1;` Something of this sort will be present at the start of your java code. If this statement is missing then you have your classes in _default_ package. Don't do that (bad practice)