# Importing classes inside JAR files that are in the default package

Tags: java, eclipse, import

How do I use Queue here?

I can't get the import to work because Queue.class is not in a package.

I have tried everything in this universe, and more.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFrrc.jpg

Comment: Ctrl-Space did not help you autocompleting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Queue` class is under unnamed package (refer [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#103097)). It can't be imported. Also, it's bad practice.

You have two options

1. Move your own code to unnamed package. Theoretically, both of them being in same package, you will not need to import `Queue` as it's class-name is suffice to find out the class.
2. Use [JarJar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) - a tool to repackage your Jar files. Repackage the Jar containing the `Queue` class and move the unnamed package to a sensible package name. Use Fully Qualified Class Name (FQCN) to import.

I would suggest to use packages and go for option 2.

---

*Edit 1*: also see this [What's the syntax to import a class in a default package in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for that, now I udnerstand how it works. The Jar-file was provided by my teacher to be used in the lab assignment, heh.