# Why is my object not a member of package <root> if it's in a separate source file?

Tags: scala, package

I'm having a problem accessing an object defined in the root package.  If I have all my code in one file, it works fine, but when I split it across two files, I can't get it past the compiler.

This works fine:

All in one file called `packages.scala`:

```
object Foo
  val name = "Brian"
}

package somepackage {
  object Test extends App {
    println(Foo.name)
  }
}
```

Witness:

```
$ scalac packages.scala
$ scala -cp . somepackage.Test
Brian
```

But if I split the code across two files:

`packages.scala`

```
object Foo {
  val name = "Brian"
}
```

`packages2.scala`

```
package somepackage {
  object Test extends App {
    println(Foo.name)
  }
}
```

it all fails:

```
$ scalac packages.scala packages2.scala
packages2.scala:3: error: not found: value Foo
```

So I try to make the reference to `Foo` absolute:

```
...
    println(_root_.Foo.name)
...
```

But that doesn't work either:

```
$ scalac packages.scala packages2.scala
packages2.scala:3: error: object Foo is not a member of package <root>
```

If `Foo` is not a member of the root package, where on earth *is* it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think this is the relevant part in the spec:

> Top-level definitions outside a packaging are assumed to be injected into a special empty package. That package cannot be named and therefore cannot be imported. However, members of the empty package are visible to each other without qualification.

Source [Scala Reference §9.2 Packages](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

But don’t ask me why it works if you have the following in `packages2.scala`:

```
object Dummy

package somepackage {
  object Test extends App {
    println(Foo.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I wonder if defining the Dummy object puts an implicit "package <emptypackagethatcannotbenamed> {" at the start of the file, meaning it's in scope later on?

Comment: Looks like it does indeed: `scalac -Xprint:typer packages2WithDummy.scala` → `package <empty> { … `

Answer (score 21):

Foo is a member of the root package, but you can't refer to it. It's a generic thing with JVM languages, (see [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package) for Groovy, [What's the syntax to import a class in a default package in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java)). It's the same for Scala.

From the Java answer:

> You can't import classes from the default package. You should avoid
>   using the default package except for very small example programs.
>
> From the Java language specification:
>
> > It is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.

The reason it works in one single file is because everything is available to the compiler at once, and the compiler copes with it. I suspect that this is to allow scripting.

Moral of the story: don't use the default package if you're not scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this when trying to import the main `App` entrypoint into a test. This may be an evil hack, but putting `package scala` at the top of the entrypoint definition seems to have made the object globally available. This may be evil, but it works.

E.g.
/src/main/scala/EntryPoint.scala

```
package scala

object EntryPoint extends App {
  val s = "Foo"
}
```

/src/test/scala/integration/EntryPointSuite.scala

```
package integration 
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class EntryPointSuite extends FlatSpec {
  "EntryPoint" should "have property s" in {
    val ep = EntryPoint.main()
    assert(ep.s == "Foo")
  }
}
```