# scala: can't import object from root scope

Tags: scala, import, package

I Have the following code:
(src/main/scala/coins/coins.scala)

```
object Main extends App { 

  def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
  [...]
```

And I'm trying to reference it from a test like this:
(src/test/scala/coins/CoinsSuite.scala)

```
package coins

import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class CoinsSuite extends FunSuite {

  import Main.countChange
  test("only onw way to pay $0") {
  [...]
```

And I get the following error:

not found: value Main
[error]   import Main.countChange

But on the other hand, from an sbt console it works fine

If I declare any package in the main file, like

```
package x

object Main extends App { 
  Console.println("Hello World!")
```

Then I can correcly issue 
    import x.Main.countChange

Is there limitation on root package or on singleton objects visibility that I'm not aware of?

-- added

just to complete the answer, a couple of useful links at SO

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030159/47633

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822212/47633

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822227/47633

Comment: So `Main` is in `/coins` directory, but not in `coins` package? BTW try `import _root_.Main.countChange`.

Comment: I tried it: object Main is not a member of package <root>

Comment: I tried several options, that's why Main ended up in the /coins directory, but packages in scala are unrelated with directory structure, as far as I know...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java (and Scala according to the same convention) is grumpy about importing things in the unnamed package, which is not the same thing as the root package.  Put `Main` into a package.

See [Why is my object not a member of package <root> if it's in a separate source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822008)

Comment: What if you cannot put it into a package?

AWS Glue job scripts don't allow that at all, so it's not always an option.