# object myClass is not a member of package <root>

Tags: scala, package

```
object myClass is not a member of package <root>
import _root_.myClass
```

```
//test1.scala 
import _root_.myClass

object test1 {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(this.getClass.getName)
  }
}
//myClass.scala 
case class myClass(){
}
```

Everthing... renaming the class to include the *root*
... Note that they are not in the same file

Comment: Are those actually in the same file? What is the perceived benefit of importing a class in the same file it's defined in?

Comment: No they're in separate files

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `myClass` is not a member of package `_root_`. It's in the package `_empty_`.

If you put everything in the package `mypackage` then you'll be able to import with `_root_`

*src/main/scala/mypackage/test1.scala*

```
package mypackage

import _root_.mypackage.myClass

object test1 {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(this.getClass.getName)
  }
}
```

*src/main/scala/mypackage/myClass.scala*

```
case class myClass()
```

For `myClass` from my code, `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.symbolOf[myClass].owner` returns `package mypackage`. For `myClass` from your code, it returns `package <empty>`.

A couple of quotes from the spec:

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/09-top-level-definitions.html

> Top-level definitions outside a packaging are assumed to be injected into a special empty package. That package cannot be named and therefore cannot be imported. However, members of the empty package are visible to each other without qualification.

> If a package name is shadowed, it's possible to refer to its fully-qualified name by prefixing it with the special predefined name `_root_`, which refers to the outermost root package that contains all top-level packages.
>
> The name `_root_` has this special denotation only when used as the first element of a qualifier; it is an ordinary identifier otherwise.

[What is the _root_ package in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687071/what-is-the-root-package-in-scala)

[scala: can't import object from root scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762837/scala-cant-import-object-from-root-scope)

[Why is my object not a member of package <root> if it's in a separate source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822008/why-is-my-object-not-a-member-of-package-root-if-its-in-a-separate-source-fil)

Comment: Please note that the code isn't in the same file.

Comment: @Th333w1 Ok, I modified my answer. This doesn't change much. Important is that `myClass` and `test1` are in the same package, not that they are in the same file. Anyway you don't have to import a class from the same package.