# PlayFramework 2 cannot import a tag when view-structure is deeper than 0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

If I have a structure:

```
/app/views/tags/tag1.scala.html

/app/views/mystuff/tags/tag2.scala.html
```

Then, inside `tag2.scala.html`

```
@import tags._  // this refers to /app/views/mystuff/tags
@import _root_.tags._ // I want it refers to /app/views/tags
```

Then I have an error: **object tags is not a member of package**

**Q:** what is the best practice to handle `imports` if the view-structure is deeper than one level ?

**REMARK:**
*I've already [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822008/why-is-my-object-not-a-member-of-package-root-if-its-in-a-separate-source-fil) that `_root_` can not be imported. But how can I refer to the root then?*

**UPDATE**:

If I try this (not to use **root**):

```
@import views.tags._
@import views.mystuff.tags._
```

Then I have error: **object tags is not a member of package views**

Answer (score 0):

The package "views" need to be the last in structure path, so you must change your structure from:

```
/app/views/mystuff/tags/tag2.scala.html
```

to:

```
/app/mystuff/tags/views/tag2.scala.html
```

Comment: You asked a totally different question from the question raised at that remark. Have you tried the code? I'm pretty sure that it works.

Comment: Yes, I did, it (also) says: "object tags is not a member of package views".
In may remarks I refer to the answer that refers to the doc that says that it is impossible to use _root_ in import. Do you use similar snippet/root-import somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

For now I follow different structure:

```
tags/tag1.scaa.html
tags/mystuff/tag2.scala.html
```

and this of course works (maybe this is even better).

Another idea is to create separate `play module`. Or even different `(rest) application`.. depending on what '**stuff**' is in each concrete case.

---

So this is alternative solution, I don't know how to refer to root in that case: