# Java Packages: Newbie on modifying system default package to a named package

Tags: java

I'm new to java and packages and need some help navigating them. Currently I have a functioning java program for a web application where all my .java and .class files sit in the `myapp/WEB-INF/classes` directory on a linux server:

```
myapp/WEB-INF/classes/MyJavaClass1.class
myapp/WEB-INF/classes/MyJavaClass2.class
myapp/WEB-INF/classes/MyJavaClass3.class
```

None of these files include a line of code for `package` so I assume the system default package is being used.

Then I added a `mytools` directory, and created a new class in there.

```
myapp/WEB-INF/classes/mytools/MyToolClass1.class
```

But it seems like this new class cannot access the classes in the `myapp/WEB-INF/classes` directory unless those java files include a package name. So my question is how to change the files to go from a system default package (e.g. no package specified) to a named package?

Should I append `package mypackage;` to the first line of MyJavaClass1.java, MyJavaClass2.java, and MyJavaClass3.java, and append `package mypackage.mytools;` to MyToolClass1.java?

Or, do I also need to create a directory `mypackage` such that `myapp/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage` and place the files MyJavaClass1.class etc. in there, before doing the above?

Then when I compile the .java files, do I compile each within their own directory (or do all files need to be compiled from top level directory)?

UPDATE 1

If I simply keep the default package (i.e. no package) for the java files in `myapp/WEB-INF/classes`, and append:

```
package mytools;
import MyJavaClass1;
```

to MyToolClass1.java and try to compile MyToolClass1.java from the `mytools` directory, I get the following compile errors:

```
MyToolClass1.java:21: '.' expected
import MyJavaClass1;
                   ^
MyToolClass1.java:21: ';' expected
import MyJavaClass1;
                    ^
2 errors
```

Comment: You cannot access classes in default package from a named package. Please see this link for similar discussion [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)

Comment: Thanks sperumal, The most help that link gives is "So to access a default package class from within a packaged class requires moving the default package class into a package of its own." Which is where I'm stuck (that's where my questions begin above). For example, does including a `package mypackage;` at the top of MyJavaClass1.java qualify as moving the default package class into a package of its own, or do I need to create a `mypackage` directory and move MyJavaClass1.java and .class there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java packages are defined at the top of the class as you described.  Your code is working only because all code is at the root, i.e., no package.  I recommend that you move all your classes into a package... move them all into the mytools dir and add `package mytools;` to each.

For a quick reference on package best practices, read through this [package tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).  You'll probably want to package your classes by related function, meaning some may go into mytools directory and some my go into mytools/parse (`package mytools.parse;`)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's the approach I started with. See UPDATE1 above. But it seems to give compile errors as shown. Perhaps for these reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java?rq=1

Comment: OK, then it's not as simple as just including a `package mypackage;` at the top of the file? That is, I actually need to create a `mypackage` directory and place the files inside there? And then once that's done, I create a `mypackage/mytools` directory and place MyToolClass1.java in there with `package mypackage.mytools;` as the first line.

Comment: correct.  the directory structure from your classes directory should match your package declaration