# Unable to compile class for JSP. Class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%@page import="<PackageName>.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<%  
int propertyCount=0;
ArrayList<String> MsgFlow =new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ProValue= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> PropertyKey= new ArrayList<String>();
if(request.getAttribute("Populate")!=null){

BeansOverride beans = new BeansOverride();
beans = (BeansOverride) request.getAttribute("Populate");

MsgFlow = beans.getMsgFlows();  
ProValue = beans.getProValue();
PropertyKey = beans.getPropertyKey();
MsgFlow.add("Abd");
ProValue.add("Name");
PropertyKey.add("Fjrk");

propertyCount = MsgFlow.size();
}
%>
```

error

HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

---

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

```
exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /Home.jsp
BeansOverride cannot be resolved to a type
15: ArrayList<String> PropertyKey= new ArrayList<String>();
16: if(request.getAttribute("Populate")!=null){
17: 
18: BeansOverride beans = new BeansOverride();
19:     beans = (BeansOverride) request.getAttribute("Populate");
20:     
21:     MsgFlow = beans.getMsgFlows();
```

Comment: You need to import class `BeansOverride`!

Comment: when imported class file i got this error..........
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\work\Catalina\localhost\BlueShieldBarOverride\org\apache\jsp\Home_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.cts.BeansOverride resolves to a package

Comment: Maybe `com.cts.beansoverride.BeansOverride` or so?. By the way you may write `<%@page language="..." import="..." import="..." ... %>` (with linebreaks likely).

Comment: @Joop: the "resolves to a package" error from JSP compiler while you're 100% positive of the valid FQN is under the covers a simple `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. This should give sufficient hint where the problem is.

Comment: user2767622: I warmly recommend you to stop writing Java code in JSP files. [This technique is completely obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202). Write Java code in a real Java class. In this particular case, you need to create a [servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and put the code in `doGet()` method. You'll ultimately not only end up with more simple, clean and easy-to-maintain code, but you'll also get more clear compiler errors and runtime exceptions which are more easy to understand and fix than those cryptic JSP *scriptlet* errors.

Answer (score 0):

It can not find the class `BeansOverride`

Change

```
<%@page import="<PackageName>.*" %>
```

so that it includes the package of `BeansOverride`

based upon your comments, you need to match the class package name with the jsp import name.

So. Change class to

```
package com.cts;
```

As mentioned in [What's the syntax to import a class in a default package in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java)

It is illegal to import a class from

Comment: geting same error:::  BeansOverride cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: So what classes in the packages BeansOverride do you want to use?  Is the class availblee for your webapp (on the classpath)?

Comment: BeansOverride is a class, its not a package...... how to know that class is available in webapp???

Comment: According to the error you posted 'com.cts.BeansOverride resolves to a package' so maybe it should be 'com.cts.BeansOverride.BeansOverride'?

Comment: Go on, show me the code of BeansOverride.java.  And also what you have changed your JSP topline to.

Comment: public class BeansOverride {
 String BarPath;
 String PropetyPath;
 ArrayList<String> MsgFlows = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> ProValue= new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> PropertyKey= new ArrayList<String>();
 String INPUT_ZIP_FILE;
 ArrayList<String> Development = new ArrayList<String>();
 
 ..............and their setter and getter method...............
 }

Comment: <%@page import="com.cts.BeansOverride"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>BAROVERRIDE GENERATOR</title>
</head>

<%
int propertyCount=0;
ArrayList<String> MsgFlow =new ArrayList<String>();
if(request.getAttribute("Populate")!=null){