# How to import a class from default package using reflection api

Tags: java, reflection

I want to import a class from default package. it will show compile time error as per Java language specification. So I need an example to load the class from default package using Reflection API.

I got Idea to use Reflection for that but did n't get any example to import class from Default package using Reflecion

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about something like this? http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030210/916225) answer.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion