# Issues with gradle multi-module dependency injection scope (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-injection

I have a gradle project with multiple modules. The modules have dependencies on one another. So far so good. For classes within the java package - this works fine and the objects are imported as expected. However, if I create a new package within java package and place the exact same class inside, gradle no longer seems to be able to find the classes to import. I have attached an image to show this:

[image]

This is my settings:
[image]

This is the build.gradle for the integration module (injecting models from integration-model package):

[image]

I'm clearly doing something wrong but have gone round in circles trying to figure out what. Would appreciate the help. Totally stuck on this one, definitely comes down to some intellij module definitions in project structure but unsure.

Comment: Did you know that [you can't import classes from the default package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030159/104891)? Is that the case? If not, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated with further data, no i am merely importing classes from another package within the default.