# Packages in Java / intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

This is more an question about intellij (I think).
Recently updated my intellij and some of my prferences have been changed 
when a class is put into a package it can no longer access any other classes, When starting a new project I have clicked auto import as always but it will not allow me to extend a class from an abstract class without both classes being at the same level.
Also when starting a new project a java module is no longer generated.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI0wb.png)

Thank you for your help in advance (If you have not already guested I am farily new to programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import a Class from the default package.

Move the `Player` class into a package and everything will work fine.

See: [What's the syntax to import a class in a default package in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java)