# Java: Why does Import not work when trying to import a class from the src?

Tags: java, import

I have the following code (note that I'm posting a photo instead of copy-pasting code because the project structure is also relevant):[image: Code]

I believe the error is because Seriallizer is in the io package and can't see GraphEditor. Howerver I've tried a lot of imports like `import GraphEditor;` `import src.GraphEditor;` `import GraphEditor.src.GraphEditor` but none worked and I reckon I'm missing something. Thank you!

Comment: File structure looks fine to me. Have you tried to compile the code via the command line? Seems like a project setup issue.

Comment: It looks like your GraphEditor is in the "default" package, i.e. it doesn't have a package. Move it to a package and you should be able to import it (you will need to add the package statement to the file, and move it on the file system to achieve this)

Comment: Try using `src/main/java` as root for you classes

Comment: @Turing85 I ve just tried to compile it with javac GraphEditor.java and it finds some errors but when running it in IntelliJ it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can't import from the default package. See [What's the syntax to import a class in a default package in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java)

The simplest thing to do here is to make sure everything has a package. Usually people create a root package for their project to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

All `import` does is let you reference classes in your source without the package name

So for instance,

```
import java.io.InputStream
```

lets you create a variable

```
  InputStream myInputStream;
```

instead of having to use

```
  java.io.InputStream myInputStream;
```

Finally, it seems like GraphEditor doesn't have a package. I forget if/how you can reference other classes in the default domain space (i.e. no package), but if you gave it a package and moved it the the appropriate place in the file system, that might resolve your issue