# is it possible for extending a class file from outside the package to the package

Tags: java, class, import, package, extends

i am beginner to java . i am having issue with importing a class to the package file from outside the package

[image]

here i am having a package named mypack and inside it there is class file named **abc**. **outside the package** i have an another class file named **pacl** and i want to import class from **pacl** to the **abc**(which is inside the package). does java support this . i have searched the web and haven't got the answer

Comment: Check out the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java#:~:text=You%20can't%20import%20classes,type%20from%20the%20unnamed%20package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pacl` class is in the default package, and [therefore can't be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java/2030159#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20import%20classes,type%20from%20the%20unnamed%20package.). You'll need to put it in a package if you want to import it to classes in other packages. In fact, you shouldn't be using the default package if at all possible, specially if you have multiple classes in various packages.