# cannot find symbol(Java)

Tags: java

I get an error in my code that can't find the symbol and I've searched everywhere but still can't find the solution. this file is separate

```
    class P1 {
    protected void aFancyMethod() {
        System.out.println("what a fancy method");
    }
}

public class P2 extends P1 {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        P2 p2 = new P2();
        p2.aFancyMethod();
    }
}
```

my error same...

```
    P2.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class P2 extends P1 {
                        ^
  symbol: class P1
P2.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        p2.aFancyMethod();
          ^
  symbol:   method aFancyMethod()
  location: variable p2 of type P2
2 errors
```

Comment: It looks like those are two separate files, despite what your sample shows.  If the file `p2.java` needs something in `p1.java`, you have to import it.

Comment: @TimRoberts - But there are restrictions on importing from the default package; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030159/139985.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have separate file for classes `p1` and `p2`... if they are named `p1.java` and `p2.java` and they are in same directory then it would be fine doing:

```sh
javac p2.java
```

However if you have `P1.java` (with capital P) or any other filename for class `p1` then javac will not be able to find source code for compilation of class `p1` when compiling class `p2`.

Check your filenames. (I don't know whether this problem will exist on non-case-sensitive os like windows.)

Alternative this should be fine regardless of filename:

```sh
javac *.java
```

Anyway the recommendation is:

- Class names start with capital letter
- Each class is in it's own `.java` file.
- name of java file matches with classname exactly including letter case.