# Import class in file jsp

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

A class that is in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` and the `.jsp` file doesn't read that class.

I have a class called `DbUtilities` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` directory. The `index.jsp` file doesn't read that class.
Running the application, I have this error:

```
An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [/usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/UsersLoginTomcat/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The import DbUtilities cannot be resolved
```

```
An error occurred at line: [33] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
DbUtilities cannot be resolved
```

Comment: By 'class', I'm assuming you mean a Java source file, not the compiled class; You've included a 'maven' tag, so I'm assuming you're using Maven to build a war file; Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: No, i use a `.class` file and yes I use maven to build a war

Comment: OK, is the `DbUtilities` class in a package?

Comment: No, is directly in `classes`

Comment: That's not what dictates whether or not the class is in a package; is there a `package` declaration in the source for `DbUtilities`?

Comment: Maybe check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package

Comment: Not package declaration in the source file, only import of classes

Comment: Have you checked the class file is in the war file?  I think the Maven war plugin might treat the `classes` directory as special, as in it expects to create it.  If you put `DbUtilities.class` in `src/main/resources`, the Maven war plugin will put it in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory in the war file when you run the build.

Comment: In the `target` directory is effectively under `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: In the war or on your file system?

Comment: in both, also in the war

Comment: Right, sorry I'm being daft - Java does not support imports from the default package; see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030148/whats-the-syntax-to-import-a-class-in-a-default-package-in-java.  In short, you need to put `DbUtilities` in a package.