# Is Intellij supposed to use autocompletion for classes you import, just like it would eg for JFrame?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete

If I type import javax.swing.JFrame; at the top of my file, and then in a method definition I type "JFra", it will autocomplete it to "JFrame", but if I type "import MainFrame;" at the top of my file, and then in a method definition I type "Mai", Intellij doesn't give me an autocomplete suggestion for MainFrame. Is this how it's supposed to be?

Comment: `import MainFrame` doesn't look right as it lacks part about *package* where `MainFrame` is declared (note we can't import classes from default package, more info: [What's the syntax to import a class in a default package in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030148)). Also are you sure that `MainFrame` is available at the time you want to use/autocomplete it? Note that if it is in other package it will need to be public and compile without problems. If it is in same package you don't need to import it.

Comment: Yes, if you import the class and don’t get any error message from your import statement, then IntelliJ IDEA should autocomplete the class name in places where it expects a class name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.